# Infinite scrolling text without gap and with dinamically changing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this issue with something like old deprecated `<marquee>`. Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbqz0kay/1/

It's one (and simpliest) of hundreds of attempts. I can't resolve main issues:

1. how to remove the gap between end and (new) beginning of the list (it should be like one infinitely scrolling sentence). I've tried with removing first `li` elements and adding them to the end but it affected overall dimensions of the list and in consequence - the animation was disrupted.
2. part of the list will be changing once in a while (site is connected to websocket) and every change in its content affect dimensions of the list also. So again - problem with stuttering animation occured.

Any ideas how to handle this? I've seen many ready-made examples but none of them handles those two issues.

Comment: Found this plugin: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee i hope it will help.

Comment: Thank! That plugin works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Marquee` can't help you in this case, as you can't achieve continuous scrolling using this element. Instead, just a bit of javascript might do the trick here. I tried this example which is also very well documented on my own blog and worked perfectly fine, more on this article:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm